# Number of words in array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, max, limit

How many maximum words can i store in String array in java? I am working on machine learning algorithms and my requirement is huge approximately 3000 words. Suggest me any alternative to process that data because i have tried with array and it is not working.

Comment: You can't hold 3000 references in a String[]?! Could we see the code you tried

Comment: `3000` is not a huge number. You should show some code to determine what the real issue is.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/524745/java/java/Maximum-capacity-arrayList-String-objects

Comment: 3000 words should work just fine. 9000 000 pairs or words could be worse.

Comment: Are you getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception?

Comment: Please provide more details besides "it is not working".

Comment: No, the maximum capacity of an array. it depend on amount of memory the JVM has available.

Comment: @Richard: yes it is giving me array out of bound exception. It would be kind of difficult for me to upload the code as it is too big. But the main idea is i am reading every file in a folder and saving their words in array

Comment: Right! In that case I know the problem, you're doing String[] strings=new String[3000]; strings[3000]="something"; but strings[2999] is the last entry

Comment: If you can include a bare minimum code showing how String[] is declared and where it is used when it throws the exception, as well as the exception itself we can answer this

Comment: P.s. do you know how many words there will be in advance or are you looking for some sort of extendable array

Comment: I have declared array like this way: static String []words

Comment: and i am just adding every word from file

Comment: 3 billion is huge. 3 thousand isn't.

Comment: ArrayList should help you out.....

Comment: @Boann: then what could be my problem exactly coz i have stated its declaration in earlier comments and i am just adding every word

Comment: @user2773586 **But** do you know in advance that you will have 3000 words, or is that a guess

Comment: its an approximate guess

Comment: @user2773586 In that case I'm 90% sure you ended up with more than 3000, hence the issue, see my answer regarding ArrayLists for Array type behaviour but when total size is unknown

Comment: @RichardTingle: Thanks mate it was a great help from you now my motive is solved it is working with arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stated you are recieving an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception, this is because you are using more than the stated size of the array

```
String[] strings=new String[3000];
strings[3000]="something";//causes exception because strings[2999] is the last entry.
```

If you know how many entries you require then declare an array of that size, or if you need an array style container that can be extended use an arraylist.

```
ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("Something"); //can be added as many times as you want (or that available memory will allow)
```

ArrayLists automatically resize as you add items to them, they are ideal when you want list behaviour (i.e. things are in an order) but don't know in advance how many items you will have.

You can then retrieve items from the list as you see fit, most common methods are;

```
String string=strings.get(0); //returns the first entry
int size=strings.size(); //tells you how many items are currently in the array list
```

#### Notes

You can improve ArrayList performance by telling it how big you expect it to be, so `ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>(3000);` but this is entirely optional

Comment: Yeah sure new to stackoverflow dint know about it

Comment: @user2773586 Mainly it just marks that your problem is solved (although people can still add new answers). Don't let anyone (myself included) bully you into accepting however, and you can always change your accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can find how much memory you have for your disposal at JVM by using this code :

```
long maxBytes = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
System.out.println("Max memory: " + maxBytes / 1024 / 1024 + "M");
```

Note that if you want to know how much strings in array you can have, devide the whole number by ~64, which is average length of String. (counting all the references etc.)

```
System.out.println("Max words: " + maxBytes / 64 + " words");
```

If you have average machine, you should have at least 2GB RAM at your disposal just for allocating variables, which is ~30 milions average words.

Comment: While this is useful information it doesn't strictly speaking answer this question

Comment: 450 million words in 2 gigabytes would imply 4.7 bytes per word. But given that a char is 2 bytes, and the char array has an 8-byte object header and a 4-byte length, and the object size is probably rounded to a multiple of 8 or 16 bytes for organization on the heap, plus the String object's char[] pointer and two different cached hashCodes at 4 bytes apiece, and the String object header and the reference needed to point to the String object, a typical String word is probably closer to 64 bytes, or ~33.5 million in 2 GB.